# Number of ways to pass edges of a cycle exactly n times

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Consider an undirected network consisting of a single cycle with 6 nodes according to the below image with a given starting node.

Is there a way to get an expression for the number of paths one may take to pass each edge exactly n times?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? Where did you get stuck?  You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Your graph has only 5 nodes.